# Phonegap Download file in iOS with File-Transfer and access to it in the device

Tags: ios, cordova, file-transfer

I created an application using Phonegap and jQuery Mobile, it works great in an iPad mini, and I'm using File-Transfer to download a file in the device, the log says the file was successfully downloaded but I can't find the pdf document anywhere in the device, this is my code:

```
function iosDownload() { 
    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer(); 
    var uri = encodeURI("WEB_SERVICE_URL"); 

    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fs) { 
        var fileNamePath = fs.root.fullPath + "/file.pdf"; 
        fileTransfer.download( uri, fileNamePath, function(entry) { 
            console.log("download complete: " + entry.fullPath); 
            alert("Reporte generado exitosamente"); 
            }, function(error) { 
                console.log("download error source " + error.source); 
                console.log("download error target " + error.target); 
                console.log("upload error code" + error.code); 
                alert("Error al generar reporte. Intentar mas tarde"); 
            }, false, { 
                headers: { 
                    "Authorization": "Basic dGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA==" 
                } 
            } 
        ); 
    }); 
}
```

The response in the log shows this path:

**download complete: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/DEVICE_UNIQUEID/Documents/file.pdf**

I cannot find the document, is there any way to download it in the Downloads folder? or is there any way to find it in that location? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Look into this file path

```
Users/YourAccount/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/45BCFA0B-C37A-4A85-A63C-(device's ID)/data/Containers/Data/Application/E4472D7E-A833-4985-89CF-(App's ID)/Documents/yourfile.pdf
```

Hope that help.
Same path you saved.

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fs) { 
    var fileNamePath = fs.root.fullPath + "/file.pdf"; 
    $scope.fileToShow = fileNamePath;

}
```

HTML

```
<div>fileToShow</div>
```

If you want to see your pdf on your iPad, install iExplorer

[iExplorer](https://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/)

Connect your iPad and open iExplorer. Then go to Files and Apps,and select your application. Your pdf will be under Documents.

Comment: Thanks, but that's for the simulator, where I can find the files, but I'm running the application in mi iPad right now, where I cannot find them.